# How to convert all Series values of a Dataframe from timedelta to minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have this dataframe where every value's type is timedelta:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

And I want to transform all values to minutes, but when coding:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].seconds/60
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'
```

How can I transform every value of the column in a simple way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `DatetimeIndex` series, you can access to a special accessor `dt` which give you some attributes and methods:

```
df['min'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print(df)

# Output
             time   min
0 0 days 00:53:00  53.0
1 0 days 00:45:00  45.0
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:53:00'),
                            pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:45:00')]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.dt.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds() / 60
```